# How to use np.save to save files in different directory in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to save training in a different folder named `Check`. How can I save this using `np.save` command? I read about `np.save` command from documentation but it doesn't describe how to save it in different directory.

```
sample = np.arange(100).reshape(10,10)
split = 0.7
index = int(floor(len(sample)*split))
training = sample[:index]
np.save("Check"+'train_set.npy',training)
```

Comment: <!> beware that any directories in your absolute path must already exist, `.save()` will not create missing dirs

Answer (score 9):

From the ([DOCS](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)):

> file : file, str, or pathlib.Path
>
> File or filename to which the data is saved. If file is a file-object, then the filename is unchanged. If file is a string or Path, a .npy extension will be appended to the file name if it does not already have one.

This states that if the filename has a directory (ie: Path), it will be stored there. So something like this should do what you need:

```
import os
np.save(os.path.join('Check', 'train_set'), training)
```

Comment: How I can save it in documents? should I mention x=os.path.join('Documents' , 'Check') and then np.save(x , '/train_set' ,training)

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: So the `os.path.join()` is used build the paths.  It adds them together in a way that will work on any OS.  But what is not mentioned is where the path *starts*.  If the path does not start at a specific place, then it is relative to what ever the current directory is when the program runs. On Ubuntu I think Documents is in your home directory, so to start in Documnets, than can be built with: `docs_dir=os.path.expanduser('~/Documents')`.  Then `np.save(os.path.join(docs_dir, 'Check', 'train_set'), ...`

Comment: What's the difference between using os.path.write(x)  and using  numpy.save(x)?

Comment: @skan I am unaware of `os.path.write()`